# Updating Android SDK Tools

Tags: android, updates, android-sdk-tools

When I attempt to update the Android SDK Tools, I get the following error message:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 21.0.1
Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 21.0.1
Failed to rename directory e:\programs\java\android-sdk\tools to e:\programs\java\android-sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01.
[find_lock] Directory locked by java.exe
Failed to rename directory e:\programs\java\android-sdk\tools to e:\programs\java\android-sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01.
[find_lock] Directory locked by java.exe
```

After shutting down everything I can, I find that the only instance of java.exe which is running is the one used by the Android SDK Manager! So it is blocking itself from updating the SDK Tools. Is there a workaround so that I can get this update?

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. Eclipse takes some time to shut down, even after the main window disappears. Also, ADB needs to be closed; no graceful way to do that short of killing the process.

Comment: Neither Eclipse nor ADB are running. When I kill the running java.exe, it kills the Android SDK Manager as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a permission issue on your directory. You may need to go to the temp folder and make sure that user and administrator has full permissions so that the file can be changed.

Comment: FWIW, "E:" is a USB Flash Drive. I am currently in the middle of downloading API 17, which appears to have written a .zip file to the `temp` folder.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine and then updating it? This kind of goes with the other answer below. I had this same problem a couple of updates ago and ended up changing the permissions and doing a restart all at the same time and it worked. I am not sure which one fixed the problem.